# I am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')" in Google sheet while running script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add the email address of the user in a cell immediately when they edit a cell in a certain column. The code below gives `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')`.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const rowIndex = range.getRow();
  const colIndex = range.getColumn();
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const SHEET_NAME = "28th Mangsir"; // Sheet name you want to check
  const EMAIL_COLUMN = 4; // Column index where emails are written
  const TASK_COLUMN = 2; // Column index where tasks are written
  if (colIndex === TASK_COLUMN && rowIndex > 1 && sheet.getName() === SHEET_NAME) {
    const userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    sheet.getRange(rowIndex, EMAIL_COLUMN).setValue(userEmail);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would assume the error is here : ```const range = e.range;``` . Could you explain what is ```e``` ? Or eventually do a ```console.log(e)``` just at the start of your function ?

Answer (score 1):

The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that is designed to run automatically when you manually edit the spreadsheet. In that context, the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e` is properly populated.
Do not run the code in the script editor. If you do, the event parameter `e` is not populated, causing the error you mention.

Simple triggers run in a restricted context where the identity of the user at the keyboard is usually not available. *"They may or may not be able to determine the identity of the current user, depending on a complex set of security restrictions."* See [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) and [Session.getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser).

Answer (score 0):

Try using an installable trigger:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && sheet.getName() == "28th Mangsir") {
    if (e.user.email) {
      sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4).setValue(e.user.email);
    }
  }
}

function createInstallableTriggerIfNoneExists() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyEdit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyEdit").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: `ScriptApp.newTrigger()` will get a TriggerBuilder, but the code is missing the calls to actually create a trigger. An [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) will run under the account of the user who set up the trigger and is subject to the restrictions mentioned in the other answer. I think `e.user` gets the _active_ user, i.e., the account who created the trigger. See [Session.getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser).